# Can I compile *without* generating a PDF?

Tags: pdf, compiling, texpad, macos

When Texpad compiles a `.tex` file, it produces a `.pdf` in the same location with the same name. I would prefer to **not** have these PDFs actually be stored in my working file directory—it adds clutter, when I would rather just focus on the `.tex` files, and only use the `.pdf` when I need to export the project.

I desire to replicate the model I am familiar with in Overleaf: the user only sees the TeX files in their file system, even as they compile and can view the PDF preview. **It is only when the user asks to "Export as PDF" that any actual PDF file becomes relevant to them.**

Is this possible to do in Texpad? I don't care if there is actually a `.pdf` behind the scenes somewhere as I view the preview—I just am not a fan of it being plopped into my folder without asking. I've searched Texpad documentation, Texpad settings, TeX.SE, and a general search engine, and am having trouble finding a solution, or even other people attempting to do the same thing. **Is my goal misguided or ill-informed somehow? If not, how do I do this?**

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you! Could you please move this comment to the answer section?

Comment: Many pdf viewers are able to keep displaying a file after it is deleted, so you could do some scripting to generate the pdf, display it, and delete it immediately. I don't know if that also works with the built-in viewer in Texpad - maybe there is functionality in that interface that requires the file to be actually present, also it may be a problem to get the timing right.

Comment: You can compile the pdf in a different folder (say a temporary folder which you don't mind cluttering). How to do that depends on the tex editor that you use.

Comment: WHen working in "live" mode, TeXpad only updates the PDF file periodically (and instead keeps a cached version of the PDF for the user to look at). However, I don't think there's a way to turn it off completely.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of a build script that executes `pdflatex` (or any of the other compilers) and then deletes the pdf file after a few seconds, when it is hopefully already loaded by the previewer. Or even completely outside of the compilation/editor settings with `fswatch` or [similar tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac). But I agree with earlier commenters that I don't see the advantage of hiding the pdf file in the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer as requested.

If you want to see the output, you have to compile it. So your editor has to call LaTeX to produce a PDF if you want to see a PDF. Overleaf does the same, but it doesn't show you the output and auxiliary files in the file tree. Instead it has a hidden build directory in which those files are stored for your project.

I don't really see the benefit of hiding the output files on your own machine, on the contrary, I think in the long run this is more likely to produce problems than to solve anything.

If you want to do this, the engines provide the option `-output-directory` with it you can tell LaTeX to put the output and auxiliary files into a specific directory (and adds that directory to the input paths searched by LaTeX with highest priority).

I have no idea how to configure texpad to use that option though.